# different decorators for the same function

Tags: python, decorator

I have 3 decorators and want to apply each of them to a function individually to create 3 different versions of the function. For example:

```
@decorator_1
def foo1():
  blahblah

@decorator_2
@decorator
def foo2():
  blahblah

@decorator_3
def foo3()
  blahblah
```

The contents of `foo1`, `foo2` and `foo3` are exactly the same. The problem is I have to write out the function 3 times. Of course I can put `blahblah` into another function `spam` and call it inside those three functions. But I still have to create 3 separate functions and call `spam` 3 times. Is there any better way to reduce this redundancy further?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def foo():
  blahblah

foo1 = decorator_1(foo)
foo2 = decorator_2(decorator(foo))
foo3 = decorator_3(foo)
```

Comment: is it possible to keep the decorator syntax?

Comment: @RNA You can nest it, i.e. define `foo1` as `return foo()` and the decorate it. But it's ugly and a bit inefficient. Other then that there is no such way.